# Convert Oracle Merge to MySQL Update

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, merge

I'm attempting to convert an Oracle MERGE statement to a MySQL Update statement.   This particular MERGE statement only does an update (no inserts), so am unclear why the previous engineer used a MERGE statement.

Regardless,  I know need to convert this to MySQL and am not clear as to how this is done.  (side note,  I'm doing this within a JAVA App)

Here is the MERGE statement :

```
MERGE INTO table1 a
 USING 
 (SELECT DISTINCT(ROWID) AS ROWID FROM table2 
 WHERE DATETIMEUTC >= TO_TIMESTAMP('
 formatter.format(dWV.getTime())
 ','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) b
 ON(a.ROWID = b.ROWID and 
 a.STATE = 'WV' and a.LAST_DTE = trunc(SYSDATE)) 
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET a.THISIND = 'S';
```

My attempts goes something like this :

```
UPDATE table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON (a.ROWID = b.ROWID 
and a.STATE = 'WV' 
and a.LAST_DTE = date(sysdate()))
SET a.THISIND = 'S'
WHERE DATETIMEUTC >= TO_TIMESTAMP('formatter.form(dWV.getTime())', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

However, I'm unclear if this is actually doing the same thing or not?

Comment: In the `MERGE` statement you've got `formatter.format`. In the `UPDATE` you have `formatter.form`. ???

Comment: Also, digging a bit deeper, I can't see how the `MERGE` would ever update anything (assuming that `table1` and `table2` are actually separate tables). One of the `ON` conditions is `a.ROWID = b.ROWID`, and if `table1` and `table2` are separate tables (as opposed to, say, views onto a common table or one is a synonym for the other) then `a.ROWID` will never be equal to `b.ROWID`. Unless I'm not thinking of something, that is.

Comment: Or is this a non-standard use of the pseudocolumn name `ROWID` - i.e. do `TABLE1` and `TABLE2` have columns defined on them named `ROWID`?

Comment: @BobJarvis, it should be format for both.  type-o on me.   They are two different tables, and based on the logs,  the Merge is updating rows (in Oracle), but my Update appears not to work as nothing is updated (in MySQL).   ROWID is simply me using a name to stand in for the real column name as I tried to censor out any potential company related info.   Basically ROWID exists as a key in both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by you, the original Oracle `MERGE` statement only performs updates, no inserts.

The general syntax of your MySQL query looks ok compared to the Oracle version. Here is an updated version :

```
UPDATE table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b 
    ON a.ROWID = b.ROWID 
    AND b.DATETIMEUTC >= 'formatter.form(dWV.getTime())'
SET a.THISIND = 'S'
WHERE 
    a.STATE = 'WV' 
    AND a.LAST_DTE = CURDATE()
```

Changes :

- current date can be obtained with function `CURDATE()`
- `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'` is the default format for MySQL dates, hence you do not need to convert it, you may just pass it as is (NB1 : it is unclear what `'formatter.form(dWV.getTime())'` actually means - NB2 : if you ever need to translate a string to date, `STR_TO_DATE` is your friend)
- the filter conditions on table `a` are better placed in the `WHERE` clause, while those on table `b` would better belong in the `INNER JOIN`

Comment: GMB - I'll give this format a try..since my current format, no rows are being updated.  'll report back with the results

Comment: formatter is used to convert a date/time to a string within the Java app)
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

Comment: @codem1966: thanks for accepting the answer! Also, if it was helpful to you, please consider upvoting it as well by clicking the upper arrow... Thanks!